# Looping through two tables to generate a new table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to do a table valued function that returns a date and a number present for that day from a given numbers table.

I already have a function that you provide with a start and finish date to get all the dates required (dbo.Dates(@start, @finish) , and the number table, which has the numbers that i need for each day.

The tables are as follows

### Date          |

Day (datetime)

### Numbers      |

number int
name varchar

The output I require is below.

```
Date     | Number
------------------
20120501 |  1 
20120501 |  2
20120501 |  3
20120502 |  1
20120502 |  2
20120502 |  3
20120503 |   1
....
```

Comment: And your question is?  What problems are you having?  maybe some code?

Comment: Your Numbers table does not have a date column.  How do you know which number on which day?

Comment: All numbers present for each day, there is no date column on the numbers table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need all numbers on all days, then use cross join:

```
select d.date, n.number
from dbo.Dates(@start, @finish) cross join
     Numbers n
```

You then just need to put the "create function" wrapper around this to get a table valued function.

Comment: Thanks, first  time using cross join